# Simulating Same Origin Policy in one workstation

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to simulate the same origin policy with my own laptop for researching purposes.
I'd tried the following way, but it's not working:

httpd.conf:

```
...
    NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.client.es
      DocumentRoot "C:/maestro/desarrollo/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/client"
      <Directory "C:/maestro/desarrollo/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/client">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>  

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.custom.es
      DocumentRoot "C:/maestro/desarrollo/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/custom"
      <Directory "C:/maestro/desarrollo/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/custom">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>  
...
```

Now, in order to get the SOP effect I built two different mock sites:

www.client.es/index.htm

```
...
<html>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.custom.es/js/hello.js"></script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

www.custom.es/js/hello.js

```
alert("Hello.js: loaded");
```

Finally I added the proper lines to etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   www.custom.es
127.0.0.1   www.client.es
```

So I can get different mocksites from the browser as if they were real different sites.

The problem is that I was expecting Chrome/Firefox/Explorer/etc **not to be able** to get the hello.js due to the Same Origin Policy but everything is served and no error arises when I browse to www.client.es/index.htm

Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any restrictions against downloading and executing javascript in `<script>` tags from a different domain.  The restrictions are against cross-domain ajax.  What you did will work fine.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I thought it could be that easy but it still sounds a little bit weird 4 me since accepting external scripts its at least as dangerous as executing remote ajax calls. Don't you think?